# How to retrieve what filters were set on a listview using API?

Tags: api, soap-api, query, list-view

I'm trying to integrate Salesforce in another system and it's required to filter these, but the client should be fully free to use any filters he wants. Using a listview and settings its filters, he's able to create a filtered list in his Salesforce account, which I'm able to download using executeListView(). However, using chunks isn't an option, because of a limitation of the offset (max. offset = 2000) and fetching all records at once isn't an option as well, because it exhausts the server's memory.

The only option I have left, is to be able to retrieve what filters have been set for a listview and to create a query based on these retrieved filters.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, please share how to fetch these filters?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See if it helps you in some way - http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/09/20/super-listview-viewer-using-winter15-listview-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using [ListView describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_listviewdescribe.htm) you can get lots of information about your List Views.**

You can have both the details about each filter condition, the ordering and displayed fields/columns, but also **the complete, already built SOQL string**, which comes in quite handy.

Aa an option, you could **retrieve the SOQL string from a ListView Describe call**, and from that **take only the criteria (WHERE) part** to be **re-used in your code adding any additional criteria you want** (using **[Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)**).

In particular I think your use-case will require an additional criteria to chunk record selection as you need (more than 2k records and less than all of them at once).

Comment: Another option I got to just now is readMetadata(). Among other things, it'll also return an array with field, operation and value.